# How can I send and argument to a shortcut file which have multiple destinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

I'm trying to build a python script to call a shortcut file and send an argument (example: help). However, the shortcut file have multiple destin's, i.e,

In propeties the destin is: (some information was supressed)
`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Users\X\X\X\X\.espressif\idf_cmd_init.bat" "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\" "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\""`

I've tried to call with a subprocess function, but it doesn't work or I'm making mistakes when making the code. Any ideas?

Another option:
I've been started the file (.lnk) with os.startfile:

`os.startfile(r'.\\ESP-IDF Command Prompt (cmd.exe).lnk')`

It's possible to send any argument via startfile?! If yes, how? If not, any suggestions?!

Comment: You've got unbalanced quotes in your `cmd /K` command line…

Comment: A link has exactly one target. What you believe to be multiple destinations are command line arguments. If you want to append to that you're going to have to parse the .lnk file and rebuild the command line you wish to execute from that information.